# Confused How to create an Evaluation form using Django

Tags: python, html, django

so guys I'm building django Evaluation form , that show the user 4 options (agree, highly agree, disagree, neutral) I did the models and forms but I don't know how to build the views!

I tried and create the views but I think that I couldn't save the form in a proper way.

I also did create the html page , the views and html are working but when I finish and press on submit button it throw this error

```
"Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/evaluation/form/

Django Version: 2.2.3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'cal',
 'crispy_forms',
 'phone_field',
 'django_countries',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Development\LMS\django-calendar\cal\views.py" in evaluation_view
  186.             evaluation.save()

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  741.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1186.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1334.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
  1278.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1278.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
  1277.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]

File "C:\Development\LMS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in prepare_value
  1208.             if value.contains_column_references:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /evaluation/form/
Exception Value: 'Query' object has no attribute 'contains_column_references'
" 

views.py
{def evaluation_view(request):
    form = EvaluationForm()
    question = Evaluation.objects.all()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = EvaluationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            evaluation = form.save(commit=False)
            evaluation.question = question
            evaluation.save()
            return redirect('cal:calendar')
    context = {
        "form":form,
        "question": question,
    }    
    return render(request, 'cal/evaluation.html', context)}

models.py
{class Evaluation(models.Model):
    MY_EVALUATION =  (('higly agree', 'higly agree'),('agree', 'agree'),('disagree', 'disagree'),('neutral', 'neutral'))
    option = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=MY_EVALUATION)
    question = models.TextField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
}

forms.py
{class EvaluationForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Evaluation
    fields = ['id', 'option']}

evaluation.html
{{% extends "cal/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
​
{% block title %}Evaluation{% endblock title %}
​
{% block content %}

<br>
<div class="card">
  <h5 class="card-header" >تقييم الدورة</h5>
  <div class="card-body">
    <p class="card-text">
              {% for questions in question %}
          <ol><li>{{questions.question}}</li></ol>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'cal:evaluation-form' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{form|crispy}}
            {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success">
            </form>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: in views.py line `evaluation.question = question` , you are passing objects instead of string